# Conceptual approach of threads in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, iteration

Over 2 years ago, [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) gave me invaluable tips on threads in Delphi. His answers were very useful to me and I feel like I made great progress thanks to him. This post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145144/).

Today, I now face a "conceptual problem" about threads. This is not really about code, this is about the approach one should choose for a certain problem. I know we are not supposed to ask for personal opinions, I am merely asking if, on a technical point a view, one of these approach must be avoided or if they are both viable.

My application has a list of unique product numbers (named SKU) in a database. Querying an API with theses SKUS, I get back a JSON file containing details about these products. This JSON file is processed and results are displayed on screen, and saved in database. So, at one step, a download process is involved and it is executed in a worker thread.

I see two different approaches possible for this whole procedure :

1. When the user clicks on the start button, a query is fired, building a list of SKUs based on the user criteria. A Tstringlist is then built and, for each element of the list, a thread is launched, downloads the JSON, sends back the result to the main thread and terminates.

This can be pictured like this :

[image]

2. When the user clicks on the start button, a query is fired, building a list of SKUs based on the user criteria. Instead of sending SKU numbers one after another to the worker thread, the whole list is sent, and the worker thread iterates through the list, sending back results for displaying and saving to the main thread (via a synchronize event). So we only have one worker thread working the whole list before terminating.

This can be pictured like this :

[image]

I have coded these two different approaches and they both work... with each their downsides that I have experienced.

I am not a professional developer, this is a hobby and, before working my way further down a path or another for "polishing", I would like to know if, on a technical point of view and according to your knowledge and experience, one of the approaches I depicted should be avoided and why.

Thanks for your time

Mathias

Comment: Both approaches are fine. It really comes down to whether the server allows downloading multiple JSON files in parallel or not. If it does, then there is no reason not to download them in parallel. If it does not, then you have to download then serially. I would take the parallel approach a step further by throttling how many threads can run simultaneously to not overwhelm the server if there are a lot of SKUs to download.

Comment: It would be really good if more questioners put as much effort into preparing their questions, +1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : once again thanks for your advises. I will definitely look into thread throttling. As suggested by Dave Novo in his answer, I am going to measure the duration of each solutions and compare the results. Also, he mentioned that threads are not the solution to everything and I will try another solution without thread.

Comment: @MartynA :  As Nicolas BOILEAU said (french writer of the 17th century) : "What is well conceived is clearly stated, and the words to say it come easily" - well, it does not sound as good as in french but the message is clear : if you understand your problem and are able to explain it clearly, you have a better chance of getting an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider in this case is latency to your API that is producing the JSON. For example, if it takes 30 msec to go back and forth to the server, and 0.01 msec to create the JSON on the server, then querying a single JSON record per request, even if each request is in a different thread, does not make much sense. In that case, it would make sense to do fewer requests to the server, returning more data on each request, and partition the results up among different threads.

The other thing is that threads are not a solution to every problem. I would question why you need to break each sku into a single thread. how long is each individual thread running and how much processing is each thread doing? In general, creating lots of threads, for each thread to work for a fraction of a msec does not make sense. You want the threads to be alive for as long as possible, processing as much data as they can for the job. You don't want the computer to be using as much time creating/destroying threads as actually doing useful work.

Comment: I agree. The API should be able to return an array of SKUs, not just a single one. If you need to retrieve 100 SKUs, just issue a single query and fetch those 100 items at once. Creating 100 threads is a bad solution. Creating one thread that issues 100 queries is not good either.

Comment: Creating a thread costs performance, too. If you're able to, design your application to re-use (an) existing thread(s) instead of always terminating them after their job is done. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool

Comment: @dave-novo (as well as Olivier and AmigoJack) : you sir have a very good point here - I did the math and after creation and before termination of the worker thread, elapsed time is 250ms in average. Creation and destruction of the worker thread had an extra 80ms in average. A direct IDHTTP query to the API server in the main thread is 150ms in average. Not a huge difference but  makes me think about what you said : fewer threads with more work for each or... no thread at all (for this part of the process at least). Busy week-end ahead, thanks for the advise, I will look into that direction :)

Comment: @Mathmathou - thread creation and destruction is < 1ms, not 80ms. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122189/thread-startup-speed-in-delphi. The IDE adds a lot of overhead to the timing